I need help in translating my Chinese name/chop
Hi, I had my name translated many years ago. I forgot the name and meaning, etc any help would be great.

高？麥西（滕）. 西 is a transcription of "Seaton", but I can't gauge what the other part of the seal is supposed to represent. Good luck!

It seems like 高麥西騰,  西騰 is a transliteration of "Seaton" but "高麥" is not a transliteration of Rae, do you have another name that sounds like 高麥? For example, Gomez
